# Regex works in online tester not in Typescript Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have the following Regex pattern:

```
let pattern = /([^\-\/\*\+]+)/g;
```

I am splitting the inputs of a mathematical formula to ensure that they are valid.

I have tested this on both https://www.regextester.com/ and https://regex101.com/ and it is working correctly but when I run it in a TypeScript app it is not working. Say the input was `(income - outgoing) * years working` I would expect to receive:

```
["(income ", " outgoing)", " years working"]
```

but instead I'm receiving

```
["(income ", "(income "]
```

What is it I am not getting?

Edit:
This was running pattern.exec(str); rather than str.match(pattern);. Once swapped to str.match(pattern); it is working as intended thanks to @FredG

Comment: Side note: You don't need to escape most of the characters in your regex character class (except possibly for the dash, but that could be moved unescaped too to the far right).

Comment: can you add how you implemented your regex in typescript? the regex should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work. Did you try the `match` function ?

```js
let pattern = /([^\-\/\*\+]+)/g;

const str = "(income - outgoing) * years working";

console.log(str.match(pattern));
```

Comment: Thanks! I was running let matchingItems = pattern.exec(str);